# How to check if Mailx used in the past timeframe?

Tags: bash, unix, mailx

I have a mailx statement as part of a shells scipt. It is part of a condtional statement that will send an email every minute if a system is failing.

Is there a way to have mailx check if a mail was send in the last hour and only send if result is false?

```
tail -1 "/location/of/file.txt" | mail -s "Warning" test@testing.com;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a file to mark the time you send. 
e.g.

```
dowork() {
    tail -1 "/location/of/file.txt" | mail -s "Warning" test@testing.com;
    touch ./checked.txt
}
if [[ -f ./checked.txt ]] ; then
    if [[ $(expr $(date '+%s') - $(stat -c '%Y' ./checked.txt )) -gt 3600 ]]; then
            dowork
    fi
else
    dowork
fi
```

Comment: No need to use `expr`. Use `(( ))` and `>` instead of `[[ ]]` and `-gt`.

Comment: @pizza Thanks, I was hoping for a more elegant solution without using a file. But this will work just fine. Thanks for your quick response.